# set absolute path for Cookie in Go

Tags: go, cookies, cookie-path

I set cookie on requests coming at test.mysite.com, the problem is the Path parameter on the cookie is set to `/test` instead of plain `/` and this is causing issues with recognizing the cookie on different parts of the website.
How can I set a cookie with absolute path, instead of a relative one?

code:

```golang
    cookie := http.Cookie{
        Name:     "session",
        Value:    "random_token",
        MaxAge:   300,
        HttpOnly: true,
        Secure:   true,
        Path:     "/",
        SameSite: http.SameSiteNoneMode,
    }
```

cookie:

```json
session="random_token"; Max-Age=300; Path=/test; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Domain=mysite.com
```

Comment: The code in the question creates a  cookie with the absolute path "/".   Demonstration: https://go.dev/play/p/J1EjcZsBk6a

Comment: @CeriseLimón on local there's no issue, but if the request comes to a sub-domain then the path will be /<subdomain> instead of the plain /

Comment: Where do you see the path /<subdomain> ?  Are you looking at the set-cookie header or something else?

Comment: @CeriseLimón I see it in the browser's cookie section. Set-cookie response header doesn't include the Path. Could it be the reason?

Comment: If you don't see it in `set-cookie` header - then you're running not the code you provided above but something else.

Comment: @H.Yazdani Ensure that the application calls `http.SetCookie(resp, &cookie)` before the header or data is written to the response.